# Problems with 20.04 autoinstall not picking up user-data file

Tags: server, pxe

I have a pxe server setup and can boot to pxe just fine, however autoinstall doesn't seem to pick up my user-data file.  Here is my main.ipxe file.Any ideas?

```
#!ipxe

set boot-url=http://192.168.x.x

:MENU
menu
item --gap -- ---------------- iPXE boot menu ----------------
item ubuntu ubuntu-20.04-physical
item shell          ipxe shell
choose --default return --timeout 5000 target && goto ${target}

:ubuntu
set server_ip 192.168.x.x
set root_path /pxeboot
set os_root os-images/ubuntu-20.04-server
kernel tftp://${server_ip}/${root_path}/${os_root}/casper/vmlinuz
initrd tftp://${server_ip}/${root_path}/${os_root}/casper/initrd
imgargs vmlinuz initrd=initrd ipv6.disable=1 netboot=nfs ip=dhcp nfsroot=${server_ip}:${root_path}/${os_root} autoinstall ds=nocloud-net\;s=http://192.168.x.x/pxe_ks/ubuntu-20-04-3-phys/ cloud-config-url=192.168.x.x/px_ks/ubuntu-20-04-3-phys/user-data ---

boot

boot
:shell
shell ||
goto MENU

autoboot
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found that *ipxe* does **not** want the semi-colon escaped or the kernel arguments quoted.

In your *ipxe* script you would change the argument

```
ds=nocloud-net\;s=http://192.168.x.x/pxe_ks/ubuntu-20-04-3-phys/
```

to

```
ds=nocloud-net;s=http://192.168.x.x/pxe_ks/ubuntu-20-04-3-phys/
```

If that does not work you can check your web server logs, the installer cloud-init logs (open a shell and look at `/var/log/cloud-init.log`), and the installer cmdline argument (open a shell and `cat /proc/cmdline`).

The following *ipxe* script snippet worked for me with 20.04.5

```
:ubuntu
set server_ip a.b.c.d
initrd tftp://${server_ip}/ubuntu/focal/server/initrd
kernel tftp://${server_ip}/ubuntu/focal/server/vmlinuz initrd=initrd root=/dev/ram0 ramdisk_size=1500000 ip=dhcp url=http://${server_ip}/tftp/iso/ubuntu-20.04.5-live-server-amd64.iso cloud-config-url=/dev/null autoinstall ds=nocloud-net;s=http://${server_ip}/tftp/ubuntu/focal/server/autoinstall/
boot
```